# Should site owner have social links available in the site for google to crawl and display in the profile

Tags: structured-data

eg:
  Social Links with icon in footer

[image]

Comment: If you have social media pages for the site why would you not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per latest [suggestion from google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/social-profile), there is no need for structured-data markup for social profiles.

> Social profile markup for Google knowledge panels is deprecated. We now automatically discover social profiles to include in Google knowledge panels. If you’re verified as an official representative, you can suggest a change directly. Learn more at Update your Google knowledge panel.